# Does this graph have a Euler path or circuit?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have been trying to sketch to see if there is a Euler path or circuit and I am starting to think there isn't. If someone can assure me or change my mind, I would be interested. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Have you counted the in-degree and out-degrees?  What are they?

Comment: a has 2 in 2 out, b has 4 in 3 out, c has 2 in 3 out, d has 2 in 2 out, e has 3 in 3 out, and f has 3 in 3 out.... so a Euler path must exist?

Comment: How can I find the path?

Comment: You know it starts from $c$.  Just try to build one manually.

Comment: There really is one ... keep trying ...